# How do I make a function activate automatically every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I need to make an animation that will change in sequence automatically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Shouldn't be difficult to find: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: Your edit just made your post overly broad and useless to the SO community as a whole. You should either revert your edit or update it to that it meets the posting guidelines for SO.

Comment: Agreed with Captain Oblivious.  Your original post with code made for a good question.  This revised one does not.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) helpful for this.

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myFunc, 3000);

function myFunc() {
    //do things here
}
```

The above code will call myFunc() every 3000 milliseconds, or every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for `setInterval`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

To make it change every 3 seconds, you could do something like:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function, 3000);
```

This will call the function every 3 seconds.  You may need to modify your function to get the behavior desired.

When you want it to stop, do:

```
window.clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).  Something along the lines of `setInterval(changeLight, 1000)` will call the `changeLight()` function once every second.